# Dynamic navigation bar that loads items from folder?

Tags: php, dynamic, navigation

Alright, so i am really not sure if this is even possible.
Here's what i want to do:

I have a folder called pages.
It could look like:

`index
page2
page3`

What i want to do is to list the files in a navigation bar using ul and il tags, like this:

> ul
>
> il a href="index" index
>
> il a href="page2" page2
>
> il a href="page2" page2
>
> ul

And when i update the folder with a new file, i.e. page3, it would dynamically add that one too, like so:

> il a href="page3" page3

I have no idea how to do this, i tried searching but without luck.

I know this is much to ask for, i just dont know where elso to ask.

Comment: You can list the files in a directory using `opendir()`/`readdir()` or `glob()`. What more do you need?

Comment: I am kind of new to PHP, and i dont really know how to use these functions. I am not asking you to do it for me, i just want to know how i would make them list contents in a list like i described.

Comment: you can use scandir() php function to scan the content of a directory into an array ... then you can echo the array inside a foreach loop to name each of the <li> elements.
This is something you should look for yourself in order to have a good learning experience. Hope this helps ...

Comment: Alright, thanks i am trying it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
foreach (glob("foldername/*") as $path) {
  $file = basename($path);
  echo "<li><a href="$path">$file</a></li>\n";
}
```